# I use setVisible(true) but Java Swing Window will not appear

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I don't use anything IDE.

```
import javax.swing.*;

    public class FirstAttempt
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("My first window");
        window.setSize(100,100);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

It doesn't appear. Why?

Comment: This works on my IDE. Can you tell us how you are running it? Perhaps it's off your immediate screen for some reason - if so, try adding `window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: This works on my system. Maybe your resolution is too high, then a setSize(100,100) makes it too small and you don't see it. Try a bigger size(400,400).  Also just for testing purposes and to see whether it is being rendered behind other windows or not, add a `window.setAlwaysOnTop( true );` just **before** the `setVisible(true);`

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the window initializes visibility outside of your monitor's display area? Try adding

```
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

after your setVisible() call to ensure that the window is initialized at the center of the screen.

Comment: Answers are not for random guesses.